# Is it advisable to use Lucene for this?

Tags: solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I have a huge XML file, about 2GB in size, containing Resumes. There are thousands of resumes in this file, tagged properly. Right now I am using XPATH to query it. So is it advisable to use Lucene for the same instead of XPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything else technology related, it depends.

What Lucene gives you that you're not getting with XPath is the power of a full-text engine that supports among other things ranking and the ability to phrase queries, wildcard queries etc.

Based on your use-case I would say that at full-text search engine makes sense. That's not to say that vanilla Lucene is the best way to go (there are for example other alternatives that build on Lucene).

Answer (score 3):

Depends upon what your requirements are. If you need full-text searching and all other great features of a full-blown search engine, Lucene is the way to go. I would recommend [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which builds on top of lucene and provides a much better API and abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

2GB seems to be pretty less for which I would contruct my own inverted index (a minimal one) :) However no problem in using Lucene/Solr though. Go ahead. It will help you once your records starts doubling. However at this scale (2GB) or even much larger many real life stuff is working on databases full text searches using SQL like keyword.